# Error starting ApplicationContext: conflict with javax.persistence.Table

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I am trying to run my project using spring-boot. It is possible to deploy the code as a jar and everything works fine. The tests do fail though.

I've been trying to use different version of my dependencies and did research on possible conflicts.

This is the extract of the POM.xml containing the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        mockServletResponse.setContentType() needs 
        org/springframework/http/MediaType 
        which is in:
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:671)

The following method did not exist:

    'javax.persistence.SynchronizationType javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()'

The method's class, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/elias/Documents/Uni/HTW/3.%20Semester/KBE/%c3%9cbung/htwb-kbe-repo-template-master/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/Users/elias/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/Users/elias/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/elias/Documents/Uni/HTW/3.%20Semester/KBE/%c3%9cbung/htwb-kbe-repo-template-master/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext

2021-01-23 10:46:32.515 ERROR 6964 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@17d919b6] to prepare test instance [htw.kbe_beleg.controller.SongControllerTest@554188ac]
```

This is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< htwb.ai.KBE_Beleg:songsWS >----------------------
[INFO] Building A Songs Web Service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ songsWS ---
[INFO] htwb.ai.KBE_Beleg:songsWS:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.35:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.16.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.3.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.15.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:5.4.15.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.5.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:runtime
[INFO] +- io.github.cdimascio:dotenv-java:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.39:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:9.0.35:compile
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.5.13:test
[INFO]    +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.10:compile
[INFO]    +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.10:test
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.277 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-23T11:19:23+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I could't fix my errors using them.

Comment: What library is this: `jar:file:/Users/elias/Documents/Uni/HTW/3.%20Semester/KBE/%c3%9cbung/htwb-kbe-repo-template-master/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class`? This looks like something which is not managed by Maven, and might be the reason of the version conflict.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!